# Why is jQuery.parseJSON not a function?

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I use the following jQuery statements and I am getting the error,

> jQuery.parseJSON is not a function

My function is,

```
function Iteratejsondata() {var HfJsonValue = 
      { "Table": [{ "Emp_Id": "3", 
                    "Identity_No": "", 
                    "Emp_Name": "Jerome", 
                    "Address": "Madurai", 
                    "Date_Of_Birth": "", 
                    "Desig_Name": "Supervisior", 
                    "Desig_Description": "Supervisior of the Construction", 
                    "SalaryBasis": "Monthly", 
                    "FixedSalary": "25000.00" }, 
                  { "Emp_Id": "4", 
                    "Identity_No": "", 
                    "Emp_Name": "Mohan", 
                    "Address": "Madurai", 
                    "Date_Of_Birth": "", 
                    "Desig_Name": "Acc ", 
                    "Desig_Description": "Accountant", 
                    "SalaryBasis": "Monthly", 
                    "FixedSalary": "200.00" }, 
                  { "Emp_Id": "5", 
                    "Identity_No": "", 
                    "Emp_Name": "Murugan", 
                    "Address": "Madurai", 
                    "Date_Of_Birth": "", 
                    "Desig_Name": "Mason", 
                    "Desig_Description": "Mason", 
                    "SalaryBasis": "Weekly", 
                    "FixedSalary": "150.00" }, 
                  { "Emp_Id": "6", 
                    "Identity_No": "", 
                    "Emp_Name": "Ram", 
                    "Address": "Madurai", 
                    "Date_Of_Birth": ""
                     "Desig_Name": "Mason", 
                     "Desig_Description": "Mason", 
                     "SalaryBasis": "Weekly", 
                     "FixedSalary": "120.00" }, 
                   { "Emp_Id": "7", 
                     "Identity_No": "", 
                     "Emp_Name": "Raja", 
                     "Address": "Madurai", 
                     "Date_Of_Birth": "", 
                     "Desig_Name": "Mason", 
                     "Desig_Description": "Mason", 
                     "SalaryBasis": "Weekly", 
                     "FixedSalary": "135.00" }, 
                   { "Emp_Id": "8", 
                     "Identity_No": "", 
                     "Emp_Name": "Raja kumar", 
                     "Address": "Madurai", 
                     "Date_Of_Birth": "", 
                     "Desig_Name": "Mason Helper", 
                     "Desig_Description": "Mason Helper", 
                     "SalaryBasis": "Weekly", 
                     "FixedSalary": "105.00" }, 
                   { "Emp_Id": "9", 
                     "Identity_No": "", 
                     "Emp_Name": "Lakshmi", 
                     "Address": "Madurai", 
                     "Date_Of_Birth": "", 
                     "Desig_Name": "Mason Helper", 
                     "Desig_Description": "Mason Helper", 
                     "SalaryBasis": "Weekly", 
                     "FixedSalary": "100.00" }, 
                   { "Emp_Id": "10", 
                     "Identity_No": "", 
                     "Emp_Name": "Palani", 
                     "Address": "Madurai", 
                     "Date_Of_Birth": "", 
                     "Desig_Name": "Carpenter", 
                     "Desig_Description": "Carpenter", 
                     "SalaryBasis": "Weekly", 
                     "FixedSalary": "200.00" }, 
                   { "Emp_Id": "11", 
                     "Identity_No": "", 
                     "Emp_Name": "Annamalai", 
                     "Address": "Madurai", 
                     "Date_Of_Birth": "", 
                     "Desig_Name": "Carpenter", 
                     "Desig_Description": "Carpenter", 
                     "SalaryBasis": "Weekly", 
                     "FixedSalary": "220.00" }, 
                   { "Emp_Id": "12", 
                     "Identity_No": "", 
                     "Emp_Name": "David", 
                     "Address": "Madurai", 
                     "Date_Of_Birth": "", 
                     "Desig_Name": "Steel Fixer", 
                     "Desig_Description": "Steel Fixer", 
                     "SalaryBasis": "Weekly", 
                     "FixedSalary": "220.00" }, 
                   { "Emp_Id": "13", 
                     "Identity_No": "", 
                     "Emp_Name": "Chandru", 
                     "Address": "Madurai", 
                     "Date_Of_Birth": "", 
                     "Desig_Name": "Steel Fixer", 
                     "Desig_Description": "Steel Fixer", 
                     "SalaryBasis": "Weekly", 
                     "FixedSalary": "220.00" }, 
                   { "Emp_Id": "14", 
                     "Identity_No": "", 
                     "Emp_Name": "Mani", 
                     "Address": "Madurai", 
                     "Date_Of_Birth": "", 
                     "Desig_Name": "Steel Helper", 
                     "Desig_Description": "Steel Helper", 
                     "SalaryBasis": "Weekly", 
                     "FixedSalary": "175.00" }, 
                   { "Emp_Id": "15", 
                     "Identity_No": "", 
                     "Emp_Name": "Karthik", 
                     "Address": "Madurai", 
                     "Date_Of_Birth": "", 
                     "Desig_Name": "Wood Fixer", 
                     "Desig_Description": "Wood Fixer", 
                     "SalaryBasis": "Weekly", 
                     "FixedSalary": "195.00" }, 
                   { "Emp_Id": "16", 
                     "Identity_No": "", 
                     "Emp_Name": "Bala", 
                     "Address": "Madurai", 
                     "Date_Of_Birth": "", 
                     "Desig_Name": "Wood Fixer", 
                     "Desig_Description": "Wood Fixer", 
                     "SalaryBasis": "Weekly", 
                     "FixedSalary": "185.00" }, 
                   { "Emp_Id": "17", 
                     "Identity_No": "", 
                     "Emp_Name": "Tamil arasi", 
                     "Address": "Madurai", 
                     "Date_Of_Birth": "", 
                     "Desig_Name": "Wood Helper", 
                     "Desig_Description": "Wood Helper", 
                     "SalaryBasis": "Weekly", 
                     "FixedSalary": "185.00" }, 
                   { "Emp_Id": "18", 
                     "Identity_No": "", 
                     "Emp_Name": "Perumal", 
                     "Address": "Madurai", 
                     "Date_Of_Birth": "", 
                     "Desig_Name": "Cook", 
                     "Desig_Description": "Cook", 
                     "SalaryBasis": "Weekly", 
                     "FixedSalary": "105.00" }, 
                   { "Emp_Id": "19", 
                     "Identity_No": "", 
                     "Emp_Name": "Andiappan", 
                     "Address": "Madurai", 
                     "Date_Of_Birth": "", 
                     "Desig_Name": "Watchman", 
                     "Desig_Description": "Watchman", 
                     "SalaryBasis": "Weekly", 
                     "FixedSalary": "150.00"}]
      };

    //var jsonObj = eval('(' + HfJsonValue + ')');
    var jsonObj = jQuery.parseJSON(HfJsonValue);
```

and my page looks like this

```
 <div id="Pagination" class="page-numbers"></div>
  <br style="clear:both;" />
  <div id="Searchresult"></div>

  <div id="hiddenresult" style="display:none;">

  </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var pagination_options = {
         num_edge_entries: 2,
         num_display_entries: 8,
         callback: pageselectCallback,
         items_per_page: 3
     }
     function pageselectCallback(page_index, jq) {
         var items_per_page = pagination_options.items_per_page;
         var offset = page_index * items_per_page;
         var new_content = $('#hiddenresult div.resultsdiv').slice(offset, offset + items_per_page).clone();
         $('#Searchresult').empty().append(new_content);
         return false;
     }
     function initPagination() {
         var num_entries = $('#hiddenresult div.resultsdiv').length;
         // Create pagination element
         $("#Pagination").pagination(num_entries, pagination_options);
     }
     $(document).ready(function() {
         Iteratejsondata();
         initPagination();
     });
</script>
```

I have inspected through Firebug and saw all jQuery files have been downloaded but why is this happening?

Comment: Seems like `HfJsonValue` is already an object. why treat it as JSON and convert it to object?

Comment: @the php developer certainly that is not an object i think so... I have to eval it or use jquery to parse it...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What version of jQuery are you using? `parseJSON` was added in version 1.4.1, so if you're using earlier versions, it's not there.

Comment: This error triggers when there's an error in the JSON string you're trying to parse.

Answer (score 13):

You can also use JSON.parse(). Its natively supported on FF, Chrome,Safari and IE8 and is most likely going to be faster than the JQuery version.

If you are targeting IE7 and IE6, JQuery would be the best bet.

Answer (score 7):

What version of jQuery are you using? parseJSON is only available from 1.4.1.

Also, you can only pass a String to the function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Answer (score 3):

In your example, you don't need to parse `HfJsonValue`, it's already embedded directly, it will be correctly handled by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this error but it was due to an old javascript library I was using along with jQuery 3.

As of jQuery 3+ jQuery.parseJson has been deprecated in favor of the native JSON.parse that has the same browser support as jQuery 3

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting the same error, "jQuery.parseJSON not a function", until I updated to 1.4.4

|script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"|